# Long Start-up Time for GNU Octave

Tags: windows, octave

On a clean installation of Octave 3.6.4 for Windows MinGW on a Windows 7 machine, octave takes around 30 seconds to start every time.  From what I have seen elsewhere, this is far from normal.

By "take 30 seconds to start" I mean from the time that I enter `octave` on the command line or initialize the octave.exe executable, it takes consistently 30 seconds to give the `octave:1>` prompt.  Otherwise, it runs quite quickly, start-up is just agonizingly slow.

Something possibly relevant is that when watching resource manager, the octave process first peaks quickly in CPU usage as soon as it is called, then totally disappears in terms of CPU usage, than peaks again as it finally comes up.

I have searched for any other instances of this happening, and was unable to find any.  This happens without loading any packages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your command prompt is starting octave at a very slow rate. Personally, I prefer using Console2 as an enhancement for the command prompt as you can set a path of the `octave.exe` and have it automatically load up in the window once you start Console2. It also gives you other additional features. This might or might not fix your slow start problem but I think it's worth a try:

http://robertcorvus.com/how-to-run-octave-in-console2/